# Touch Bar typing suggestions not working globally

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar, auto-complete

I have MacBook Pro 2020 running on Big Sur.
The typing autocompletion is not working for me globally (that is, in evey app is should be availiable, e.g. apple notes).

I have the keyboard icon availiable when I focus on a text field, but when I click it it looks like that:
[image]

Tried to go to go to System Preferences>Keyboard>Text and uncheck and recheck the Touch Bar typing suggestion, but the same behaviour happens.

Any idea what should solve this?

Comment: Did you make sure you’re on latest OS? Restarted computer? Tried messing with OS/keyboard language settings? Tried starting to type something?

Comment: Yeah, tried all of the above. Actually, this issue following with me a quite long time (had this also when ran on Catalina).

Comment: What other apple apps besides notes does this not work with?

Comment: @TomGewecke hi, the same happens everywhere on macos - the type suggestions does not appear.